# JSON Deserialize to Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

I am trying to parse json and have it display in a visualforce page.

**json:**

```
{  
    "type": "success",
    "value": {
        "id": 151,
        "joke": "Chuck Norris doesn't step on toes. Chuck Norris steps on necks.",
        "categories": []
    }
}
```

**controller:**

```
public class chuckNorris {

    public List<ValueWrapper> value {get;set;}

    public class ValueWrapper {
        public String joke;
        public Integer id;
    }

    public void deserialize () {
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
        String jsonString = res.getBody();

        chuckNorris chuck = (chuckNorris)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, chuckNorris.class);
        system.debug(chuck.value[0].joke);
        system.debug(chuck.value[0].id); 
    }
}
```

I believe I am using the wrapper class correctly. If I am, how would I display the joke on a visualforce page? If the wrapper class isn't correct what needs to be changed?

Comment: Out of interest, can I ask what you are implementing the ICNDB on at the moment? It's my favourite 'test" webservice (though I'm sure it also has practical uses...). I'm mostly interested as I'm actually giving a workshop on integrating this service in a Lighting Component in London next month!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right apex based on the JSON is as below

```
public class chuckNorris{

public chuckNorris chuck {get;set;}

 public String type_x {get;set;}    //success
 public cls_value value{get;set;}

  public class cls_value {
    public Integer id {get;set;}    //151
    public String joke {get;set;}   //Chuck Norris doesn't step on toes. Chuck Norris steps on necks.
    //public cls_categories[] categories {get;set;}
  }

  public class cls_categories {

  }

  public void deserialize () {
   Http h = new Http();
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setEndpoint('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random');
   req.setMethod('GET');
   req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
   HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
   String jsonString = res.getBody();
   String jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('type','type_x');//Since type is reserved keyword
  chuck = new chuckNorris();
 chuck = (chuckNorris)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, chuckNorris.class);

  }

 }
```

Visualforce page

Use merge field like below

{!chuck.value.joke}

Vf code is below:

```
<apex:page Controller="chuckNorris"  sidebar="false" action="{!deserialize}">
   <apex:form>
      <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:outputText value="{!chuck.value.joke}"> 
         </apex:outputText>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I modified your code a bit to get rid of some errors:
   jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('type','type_x')
   chuck = new chuckNorris();

Comment: cool .Ya i did not test it but getting you general idea

Comment: I am still getting errors on visualforce:

<apex:page Controller="chuckNorris"  sidebar="false">
   <apex:form>
      <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:outputText value="{!chuck.value.joke}"> 
         </apex:outputText>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
error via developer console:

Unknown property 'chuckNorris.chuck'

Comment: make that getter setter as public in controller.. `public chuckNorris chuck {get;set;}`

Comment: thanks for the comment but it is still not working -- any other suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: @slugabed I edited the answer .Specially the VF calling it on load .Its working fine in my org .